# NodeJS reading TTY Serial

Tags: node.js, tty

I can't find any examples of simply reading a serial port on a machine using Node.JS and seems I'm not the only one looking.

Quite recently it is an included library but I can't make head or tail of it!

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.8/api/tty.html

Does anyone have an example of simply reading the serial port and just console.log the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to look at [node-serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) module source.

Answer (score 4):

@James, to configure the comport on windows try this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn 
  , command = 'MODE COM1:38400,N,8,1,P' 
  , cmd    = spawn('cmd', ['/s', '/c', command], { customFds: [0,1,2] }); 

cmd.on('exit', function(code){ 
    console.log(code);  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

On Windows this works using the v0.5.2 node.exe download, no plug-ins. It reads COM1 at 9600 baud.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var inp = fs.createReadStream("\\\\.\\COM1");
inp.setEncoding('utf8');
var inptext = "";
inp.on('data', function (data) {
    inptext += data;
});
```

Comment: But how can you set baud, parity... ? Has anybody any idea?

Comment: COM connection setting is permanent up-to reboot. Just run the mode command on Windows, eg. `mode com1: BAUD=115200 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 xon=off`

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the example on the most recent [docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/tty.html)?

```
var tty = require('tty');
tty.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.on('keypress', function(char, key) {
  if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
    console.log('graceful exit');
    process.exit()
  }
});
```

Comment: I did but can't see how that open /dev/tty.usbserial0 for example!

Comment: node tty is for accessing the console, not the serial port.